# Intermittent semi-transparent sphere in Three.js

Tags: three.js, geometry

I would like somebody to explain me how I can achieve the blue semi-transparent intermittent sphere of this example: (the one next to the intermittent red sphere)

http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials.html

I believe in first place that this is a matter of using the right material with the right settings (specially because the example is about materials) but not sure anyway.

Hopefully you do not feel my question does not deserve to be made here. I was trying to analyze it but definitely it is written in a non-friendly way  for newbies, and I've not been able to separate this part from the rest, not I find an explanation anywhere else.

Comment: Don't ever feel that "your question does not deserve to be made here". Mr.doob himself has stated that StackOverflow is the place where questions about three.js should be asked.  Also, I agree that the three.js examples collection isn't exactly newbie-friendly. To remedy this, I have attempted to create a newbie-friendly collection of examples, with detailed comments in their source code, at http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/ -- check it out, I hope they are of some help.

Comment: I made the comment because stackoverflow has the fame of crushing the newbies making "stupid" questions, and if you don't try to give an explanation right away you get lots of minus points. Read this: http://sergworks.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/why-stackoverflow-sucks/ however in doesn't seems to be the trend with three.js

Comment: I hear what you're saying. Lucky for us, the three.js community is awesome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To create, for example, a partially transparent blue sphere, you could try:

```
var sphereGeom =  new THREE.SphereGeometry( 40, 32, 16 );
var blueMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 } );
var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( sphereGeom, blueMaterial );
```

For more examples of creating semi-transparent materials, check out

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Translucence.html

If you want the sphere to fade in and out, you can change the transparency in your update or render function -- make the sphere a global object, also create a (global) clock object to keep track of the time in your initialization, for example, with

```
clock = new THREE.Clock();
```

and then in your update, you could, for example, write

```
sphere.material.opacity = 0.5 * (1 + Math.sin( clock.getElapsedTime() ) );
```

Comment: Thank you Lee, your examples are the answer for the newbies. (and others levels of course) They are very well organized, and the code is more accessible to simple human beings beginning with 3D graphics than those of the main three.js website. In fact every time I have a doubt about three.js I end up consulting the udacity course and your examples. By the way I noted you updated it yesterday, keep it up.

Comment: Comments like these are what motivate me to keep updating  :D